# There she is, there he is, there you are, and there it is

Tags: phrase-meaning

In a movie when a lady entered the room a man exclaimed: there she is! I think this means something like drawing people’s attention, kind of introducing her to the rest of public.

If we replace **she** with **he** certainly the meaning won’t change.

But if we use **you** the meaning changes completely according to [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/there-you-are): used when giving something to someone or used to mean “I told you so”.

When I replaced the personal pronouns with **it** I was surprised to find nothing (to explain the phrase), on the Internet, but Vietnam’s references.

Would you please help me to understand the meaning of these phrases?

Comment: Thank you for all your excellent answers! +1 for each one of you. I can’t decide yet which one to select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There [he/she/it] is!

is an exclamation that you have found something you were looking for. The speaker was probably wondering where she was, or at the least talking about her, when she appeared.

The reason it's not listed in the dictionaries is that, although it's a common phrase, it's not a "special" phrase - it's just a normal grammatical construction and its meaning is derived from the meaning of the constituent parts:

**There** <sub>(location)</sub> **he** <sub>(subject)</sub> **is** <sub>(verb to be)</sub> **!**

The emphasis is usually on *there* because you're emphasizing that you didn't know the location of the person (or object) and now you've found it: he/she/it is *there*.

> There you are!

can also be used in this way. It means, "I was looking for you and now I've found you" or "I wondered where you are, but now you've appeared." You wouldn't say it in the middle of a conversation; you'd say it at the start.

However, there is another meaning of *There you are!*, which is the one you found. It's not more common, it's just that the phrase itself has a particular meaning beyond the definition of the individual elements, and so it's more necessary to define it.

> Here I am!

would be the equivalent for the first person. (You can't say "There" because the here/there distinction is relative to the speaker.)

It has a similar meaning: you are announcing your arrival because you believe everyone was expecting you somehow - either looking for you, or waiting for you, or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

*"There you are!"* can be used "literally" (perhaps meaning something like *"I didn't know where you were, but now I see you are **there** [in some specific location]"*), it also has a peculiar idiomatic sense...

> *There you are! = You have arrived at [the metaphoric location of] the truth/solution/crucial point.*

This same idiomatic usage can often occur with ***we*** and sometimes with ***I***, but rarely with other personal pronouns (i.e. - native speakers wouldn't normally use *"There he is!"* to mean anything like *"He's arrived at the answer!"*). The reason for this is that it's usually used in contexts where two people are talking together in search of a solution (or one person who already knows it is *leading* the other to the answer).

Similar (often exactly synonymous) is...

> *There you go! = you've arrived at (or are accurately heading towards) the truth/your goal.*

I suspect that second version may be less common in AmE. The eponymous star of the 70s American TV series [McCloud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McCloud_%28TV_series%29) often said [“There ya’ go”](http://1heckofaguy.com/2006/03/12/there-you-go/) in contexts where he seemed puzzled by the syntax/meaning of his "catchphrase". As I recall, he often said it it what appeared to me to be inappropriate circumstances, but I can't say whether that reflected the fictional character's lack of familiarity, or that of the scriptwriters.

Answer (score 0):

[there it is](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/there%20it%20is) definition

7) there it is - That is the state of affairs.

If you have seen the movie "Amadeus" (1984), Emperor Joseph II uses this phrase alot.

Maybe something like "That's the way it is."